# R not able to generate propensity scores according to formula; no error yet no calculation

Tags: r

I want to do propensity score after multiple imputation, however I think R is faulty despite showing no error.

When loading package "cobalt", there is an incorporated dataset: lalonde_mis, which we will use for this example.

Multiple imputing data as following:

```
library(mice)
library(cobalt)
library(MatchIt)
data(lalonde_mis)

m <- 10 
imp <- mice(lalonde_mis, m = m, print = FALSE) 
imp.data <- complete(imp, "long", include = FALSE)
imp.data <- imp.data[with(imp.data, order(.imp, .id)),]
```

Now calculating the Propensity Scores:

```
imp.data$ps <- imp.data$match.weight <- rep(0, nrow(imp.data))
for (i in levels(imp.data$.imp)) {
    in.imp <- imp.data$.imp == i
    imp.data$ps[in.imp] <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race + 
                                   married + nodegree +
                                   re74 + re75, 
                               data = imp.data[in.imp,], 
                               family = "binomial")$fitted.values
    m.out <- matchit(treat ~ ps, data = imp.data[in.imp,], 
                     distance = imp.data$ps[in.imp])
    imp.data$match.weight[in.imp] <- m.out$weights
}
```

This part of the aformentioned formula should calculate and give me propensity scores:

```
imp.data$ps <- imp.data$match.weight <- rep(0, nrow(imp.data))
for (i in levels(imp.data$.imp)) {
    in.imp <- imp.data$.imp == i
    imp.data$ps[in.imp] <- glm(treat ~ age + educ + race + 
                                   married + nodegree +
                                   re74 + re75, 
                               data = imp.data[in.imp,], 
                               family = "binomial")$fitted.values}
```

**However when I look back in the dataset, both imp.data$match.weight as well as imp.data$ps remains 0; R does not show up an error though; what is happening here?**

**Edit:**
sessionInfo() for analyses

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. `str(imp.data)` gives me e.g. `$ ps          : num  0.6562 0.0414 0.2416 0.7396 0.7448 ...`

Comment: What version of R /RStudio are you using, maybe that can be the problem?

Comment: I have 3.4.3. You should report your `sessionInfo()` in the question. I would be surprised if the R version is causing this particular problem.

Comment: I also tried it with Rstudio and other R versions but it is not working; even tried re-installing both programs. Edited sessionInfo() in original post! Is the sessionInfo() much different than yours?

Comment: Can't replicate the error too with `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)`, `MatchIt_3.0.1`, `cobalt_2.1.0` and  `mice_2.30`

Comment: @ANG I also want to add that after doing multiple imputation, a warning message pops up: Number of logged events: 31. Could there be a correlation with that and the non-calculation of the propensity scores, because it was just working fine a couple days ago.

Comment: Not necessarily because I also got warning messages stating `In if (distance %in% c("GAMlogit", "GAMprobit", "GAMcloglog", "GAMlog",  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` but propensity scores are computed

Comment: If you run the code without the MatchIt part (i.e., just estimating `imp.data$ps`), do the propensity scores appear? If not, this is not a problem with Matchit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `mice` changed the variable type of the `.imp` variable in their `complete()` output from `factor` to `numeric`. Because of this, it has no levels, and `levels(imp.data$.imp)` returns `NULL`, so the loop is never run. Replace `levels` with `unique` and this should fix the error. I'm updating the `cobalt` vignette in the next release to reflect this.